# How to select and return a row but ONLY if a newer row doesn't have a value

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, window-functions

I am trying to run a query on an a table in oracle 12c that records user logins/logouts.

I only want to return rows where a user has logged in but not logged out yet.

Table looks something like:

```
TIME STAMP       | USER | ACTION | COMPUTER
01/07/2020 17:30 | John | Logout | Laptop123
01/07/2020 17:25 | Mary | Logout | PC123
01/07/2020 15:00 | John | Login  | Laptop123
01/07/2020 14:30 | Max  | Login  | Laptop235
01/07/2020 14:00 | Mary | Login  | PC123
01/07/2020 13:01 | Max  | Logout | Laptop235
01/07/2020 13:03 | John | Logout | Laptop123
01/07/2020 13:00 | Mary | Logout | PC123
01/07/2020 08:30 | John | Login  | Laptop123
01/07/2020 08:00 | Mary | Login  | PC123
01/07/2020 07:30 | Max  | Login  | Laptop235
```

Now, I want to select * from this table but only return rows where a user has logged in but doesn't have a succeeding row with a logout.

I thought about doing something with

```
SELECT * from table with a lead() function built in
```

... but I can't quite my head around how I would format it or run a query on the succeeding columns for the same user.

In the example above, I would just want to return:

```
TIME STAMP       | USER | ACTION | COMPUTER
01/07/2020 14:30 | Max  | Login  | Laptop235
```

Any thoughts/advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lead(action) over(partition by user order by time_stamp) lead_action
    from mytable t
) t
where 
    action = 'Login' 
    and (lead_action <> 'Logout' or lead_action is null)
```

Note that `user` is a reserved word in Oracle, hence not a good choice for a column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where action = 'Login' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user = t.user and t2.time_stamp > t.timestamp and
                        t2.action = 'Logout'
                 );
```

Or using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action = 'Logout' then time_stamp end) over (partition by user) as max_logout_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where t.action = 'Login' and
      (t.time_stamp > max_logout_timestamp or max_logout_timestamp is null);
```